# Observation of the 21 cm line in Radio Astronomy

Tags: cosmology, astronomy

It is a well documented fact that the observation of the 21 cm emission line is a way to probe the Epoch of Reionization. The 21 cm line comes from the hyperfine splitting between the parallel and anti-parallel alignments of the ground state electron and proton spin axes.
One can calculate the Einstein coefficient of such a transition which turns out to be $2.85 \times 10^{-15} \text{s}^{-1}$ meaning that an excited hydrogen atom would make this "spin-flip" transition to emit a 21 cm photon once every (roughly) 12 billion years.
I fail to understand a very simple point - why can then we observe a 21 cm transition line? 
Isn't it forbidden?

Comment: How does the Einstein coefficient compare to the number of hydrogen atoms in your average nebula?

Comment: I just quickly tried to check these numbers. If the number density of Hydrogen atoms is taken to be roughly $\approx 10^{6} /cm^{3}$ and assuming the radius of a nebula is a few light years i.e. $9.46 \times 10^{13} cm$, then it means we have  around (very roughly) $10^{48}$ hydrogen atoms in a nebula. Yes, that is a huge number which the overcomes the smallness or rather the probability of the atomic transition. I understand the reasoning behind your question. Thank you.

Comment: The other factor that matters here (and is the reason why you don't see this transition on Earth) is that, because of the pitifully small Einstein coefficient, you need to wait a long time for this excited state to decay. Collisions disrupt this process. As such, this forbidden transition only happens when you have a lot of material at very, very low density.

Comment: @RM2401 Minor note: Your lightyear is a factor 1e4 too small, making your estimate a factor 1e12 too small.

Comment: @pela Yes, you're absolutely right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Emission in forbidden lines can be so strong it actually dominates the light from an astronomical source, e.g. Green Pea galaxies which (at least in near-uv and optical wavelengths) are dominated by forbidden lines of doubly ionized oxygen.