# How can we estimate the frequency of the spin-flip transition?

Tags: quantum-spin, hydrogen

I was reading the [Hydrogen line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line) explanation on Wikipedia when my attention was caught by the following sentence:

> This transition is highly forbidden with an extremely small transition rate of $2.9×10^{−15}$ s$^{−1}$,[4] and a mean lifetime of the excited state of around $11$ million years.

How can we estimate the mean lifetime in the orders of million of years?
Obviously, nobody can verify the accuracy of this hypotheses! Hence I'm wondering what are the experimental elements we have to say this.

Comment: Related but unanswered: [Observation of the 21 cm line in Radio Astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400668/observation-of-the-21-cm-line-in-radio-astronomy)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it isn't feasible to experimentally observe the spontaneous emission but it is straightforward to calculate it. We cannot directly check the calculation, but we can also calculate the Einstein coefficient for the stimulated emission then measure it experimentally using a [hydrogen maser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_maser). Since we find the calculation for stimulated emission matches experiment we can be reasonably confident we correctly calculated the spontaneous emission as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wait the mean lifetime to estimate the mean lifetime. (By the way, what Wikipedia calls the decay rate is the decay constant.) The mean lifetime $\tau$ is inversely proportional to the decay constant $\lambda$: $\tau = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$ The decay rate is $dN/dt = -\lambda N$. You could measure the rates to get the mean lifetimes. I'll put some rough numbers to it, so that you can see that it's not unreasonable.

A mole of hydrogen gas contains approximately $6\times 10^{23}$ atoms. For reference, at standard temperature and pressure, a mole of gas takes up only 22.4 liters.

Suppose you had two moles of atomic hydrogen gas at room temperature. Because of the energies involved, statistical mechanics says the upper state of the 1s hyperfine splitting will be occupied half the time. So you have 1 mole in the upper state. Initially, you would have $6\times 10^{23} * 2.9 \times 10^{-15} = 1.75$ billion photons emitted in all directions per second.

It would be reasonable to measure the rate in the lab at room temperature, $\textbf{if}$ you could get that much atomic hydrogen in that state. But, we have to break up H2 molecules which causes collisions in the gas which in turn changes the occupation of the states, so masers are used, like John Rennie said.